# Flash AS3 if/else simple problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to write a smooth transition piece and I don't know what is happening. 
I left it last night and it was working, I think, now its not.

here it is.

```
function btnclick(event:Event):void
{   
    if(event.target == load1 || load2)
    { 
        trace("working");
    } 
    else 
    {
        trace("not ");
    }
}
```

on my stage, I have 3 buttons,

```
load1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnclick);
load2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnclick);
load3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnclick);
```

the 3 buttons instances are

```
load1, load2 and load3.
```

When i click buttons load1 or load2,  I get the trace "working", but when I press button load3, i am still getting "working" when its supposed to say "not"

just to check  i changed it to this:

```
function btnclick(event:Event):void
{
    if(event.target == load1 || load2) 
    {
            trace("working");
    } 
    else if (event.target == load3)
    {
            trace("not ");
    }
}
```

and the same problem, they all say "working"

Any ideas what it is that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function btnclick(event:Event):void{


    if(event.target == load1 || event.target == load2) {
           trace("working");
          } else {
               trace("not ");
           }

}
```

But I recommend you to use `currentTarget` instead of `target`:

```
function btnclick(event:Event):void{


    if(event.currentTarget == load1 || event.currentTarget == load2) {
           trace("working");
          } else {
               trace("not ");
           }

}
```

The problem with you code was in `event.target == load1 || load2`. And it is equivalent of `(event.target == load1) || (load2)` where `Boolean(load2)` is `true` if `load2` isn't `null`. So `event.target == load1 || load2` is always `true` in your case.

Comment: hello Constantiner, i dont 100% understand it. but its working. thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4):

Simple thing: Your condition is wrong!

```
if(event.target == load1 || load2) {
```

That evaluates:

```
IF (event.target == load1)
OR IF (load2 is not empty)
```

Since load2 is your button, this will be always `true`.

Change it to:

```
if(event.target == load1 || event.target == load2) {
```